# C#, Bitmap, r8g8b8 and b5g6r5 pixel data

Tags: c#, bitmap, rgb, bgr

I am extracting r8g8b8 palette from file, looks like its very easy to convert it to System.Drawing.Color struct and then fill Bitmap by using SetPixel method.

But then i've encountered b5g6r5 palette and now i don't know what to do. Is there any way to fill Bitmap class with that kind of data?

Happy new year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered converting BGR565 to RGB888 (as described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888)) and then do what you did with your RGB888 values?

Comment: Well im kinda in trouble. I have two bytes, b1 and b2. First, as i asume, contains 5 bits of Blue and 3 of green component. Second byte contains 5 bit of red and three of green component. So how to extract that data into 3 bytes: r, g, b? :(

Comment: You'll have to use the bitwise operators like |, <<, etc. In your case, assuming b1 is the most significant byte, R = (b2 & 0x1F) << 3, G = (((b2 << 8) | b1) >> 2) & 0xFC and B = (b2 & 0xF8), if i'm not mistaking. Explaining all this  operators is impossible in the limited field of a comment here.