# White is not white

Tags: android, bitmap

When dealing with some bitmaps in Android I noticed that the white used in views is not always the same white rendered on bitmaps. Consider this screenshot.

[image]

The background white is from a view with white background color.

The foreground "white" is from a white bitmap decoded from the SD card, displayed in an ImageView. This bitmap is decoded using `RGB_565` as follows:

```
BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
resample.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
resample.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, resample);
```

For reference, [here](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/2088/testaq.jpg)'s the bitmap.

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: What is the white bitmap necessary? Could have used a bunch of empty lines :P

Comment: But then: why so long, or why not just a link to it?

Comment: Linked to the bitmap instead of attaching it to the question.

Comment: The gray in the screenshot is `#f0f0f0`, for reference.

Comment: @jleedev: Interesting. Does that mean that there's no pure white in RGB_565 (16 bits)? :S

Comment: @hgpc: (I could be wrong but) there is pure white in RGB_565, and pure black. Just less precision in-between. The question is whether pure white RGB_8888 converts to pure white in RGB_565. I've come across banding issues when using 8888 images on a 565 window, but never this level of different.

Comment: @hgpc Naively converting RGB_565 to RGB_888 would give you `#f8fcf8`; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888). Unless I am mistaken, I would say that something else is going on.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue and after some experiments I noticed that commenting `<uses-sdk>` solves the problem. Any value for `android:minSdkVersion` above 3 will make this effect appear (removing `<uses-sdk>` tag effectively changes `minSdkVersion` to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565)` in your onCreate.

The default format seems to change based on SDK version and device type, so just force it to stay at RGB_565

Answer (score 1):

Had a very similar if not exact same problem, even setting inPreferredConfig to ARGB_8888 didn't help.

From what I can glean from: http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html

the problem is Android automatically dithers 24 bit images down to 16 bit, which can mess with the colors.  The link mentions you can disable this by either adding an alpha channel to your image, or loading it from the raw directory instead of as a resource.

Seen as neither of these were an option for me I found the following finally worked:

```
Paint ditherPaint = new Paint();
ditherPaint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(mDrawable.getBitmap(), null, 
                  mDrawable.getBounds(), ditherPaint);
```

Here mDrawable is of type BitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a difference between the image type and the Bitmap the ImageView is rendering on, see [Bitmap.Config](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html). Load your image in different modes and see if that helps. Take a look at [Bitmap quality and banding](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/) for more info.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I added the Bitmap.Config that I'm using (RGB_565).

Comment: Try setting the window and the image to use the same RGB mode and see what happens. Set the image as above and the window with `getWindow().getAttributes().format`. Try RGB_8888 and see if it's not white. Do you know what RGB format your original image is in?

Comment: No. How can I check the RGB format of the image (which is linked in the question, BTW)? I know it's RGB and the depth is 8, according to Mac OS X Preview.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what solved this for me:

You need to set the screen density to prevent the bitmap factory from rescaling your bitmap. This is done with the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics=new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
resample.inScreenDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
```

Comment: Sorry, this should be resample as in the original question. It is an instance of BitmapFactory.Options which then is used as parameter for the BitmapFactory.decode*-method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
resample.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
```

to

```
resample.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
```

But please note that RGB_565 contributes to a better performance, as described here:
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/performance-improvement-and-bitmap-pooling-in-android-f97b380cf965#:~:text=ARGB_8888%20has%2032%2Dbit%20color,faster%20to%20render%20as%20well.