# inPreferredConfig() not working in Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, image, format

I have an app built in Android 2.2 and I'm using `inPreferredConfig()` to switch a bitmap to `ARGB_8888` format, however, this doesn't seem to work as when checked immediately afterwards the bitmap is still in `RGB_565` format. I've tried changing it to any of the other formats and neither of those work either.

The function works fine if the phone or emulator is running Android 2.2, but anything above that fails. Does anyone know why this is happening? Is `inPreferredConfig()` depreciated in later Android versions?

---

**What I'm doing:**

I'm using the NDK with some C code I've found to run some image processing functions (taken from http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-androidndk/section5.html). The C code expects the image format to be in ARGB_8888 and although the Android documentation says that the format should already be in 8888 by default but it's definitely in 565 so I'm very confused.

I'm guessing I could convert it in C...but I'm terrible at C so I wouldn't know where to start.

My C function:

```
{
    AndroidBitmapInfo  infocolor;
    void*              pixelscolor; 
    AndroidBitmapInfo  infogray;
    void*              pixelsgray;
    int                ret;
    int             y;
    int             x;


    LOGI("convertToGray");
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapcolor, &infocolor)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }


    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_getInfo(env, bitmapgray, &infogray)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_getInfo() failed ! error=%d", ret);
        return;
    }


    LOGI("color image :: width is %d; height is %d; stride is %d; format is %d;flags is %d",infocolor.width,infocolor.height,infocolor.stride,infocolor.format,infocolor.flags);
    if (infocolor.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not RGBA_8888 !");
        return;
    }


    LOGI("gray image :: width is %d; height is %d; stride is %d; format is %d;flags is %d",infogray.width,infogray.height,infogray.stride,infogray.format,infogray.flags);
    if (infogray.format != ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_A_8) {
        LOGE("Bitmap format is not A_8 !");
        return;
    }


    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapcolor, &pixelscolor)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, bitmapgray, &pixelsgray)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap_lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }

    // modify pixels with image processing algorithm

    for (y=0;y<infocolor.height;y++) {
        argb * line = (argb *) pixelscolor;
        uint8_t * grayline = (uint8_t *) pixelsgray;
        for (x=0;x<infocolor.width;x++) {
            grayline[x] = 0.3 * line[x].red + 0.59 * line[x].green + 0.11*line[x].blue;
        }

        pixelscolor = (char *)pixelscolor + infocolor.stride;
        pixelsgray = (char *) pixelsgray + infogray.stride;
    }

    LOGI("unlocking pixels");
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapcolor);
    AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels(env, bitmapgray);


}
```

My Java functions:

```
 // load bitmap from resources
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // Make sure it is 24 bit color as our image processing algorithm expects this format
    options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
    bitmapOrig = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.sampleimage,options);
    if (bitmapOrig != null)
        ivDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmapOrig);
```

-

```
bitmapWip = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrig.getWidth(),bitmapOrig.getHeight(),Config.ALPHA_8);
    convertToGray(bitmapOrig,bitmapWip);
    ivDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmapWip);
```

Thanks, N

P.S My last question of the same subject got deleted, which is annoying as I can't find any answers to this anywhere.

Comment: If you add some code that demos what you are saying, it would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: what i know about changing the format of a bitmap using `Bitmap.Config` methods is not guaranteed all time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've updated my question with some code snippets.

If it's not guaranteed all the time is there some other way of performing the task? Perhaps I could convert it in C?

Answer (score 0):

Images are loaded with the `ARGB_8888` config by default, according to the documentation, so my guess is that it recognizes the `RGB_565` format of your bitmap and changes the config for that. I don't see why this should be a problem if the original image is of `RGB_565` format and has no transparency.

Here's the documentation - read the last bit:

> If this is non-null, the decoder will try to decode into this internal configuration. If it is null, or the request cannot be met, the decoder will try to pick the best matching config based on the system's screen depth, and characteristics of the original image such as if it has per-pixel alpha (requiring a config that also does). Image are loaded with the ARGB_8888 config by default.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig

Comment: Thanks for replying, I saw this in the documentation but I'm not convinced it's true. I've tested on a Nexus One with Android 2.3.3 and the emulator running on the same, both return RGB_565 as my image format. Only when run in Android 2.2 does it return ARGB_8888.

Comment: Like I said, I see no point in trying to load them as ARGB_8888 when the images are in RGB_565. It'll take up more memory, but won't give you any advantages.

Comment: Ok see, so you're saying I should change my C code to handle RGB_565 format instead? If Android 2.2 returns ARGB_8888 and >= 2.3 returns RGB_565 then I'll need two separate methods in C for every filter I create. This isn't ideal, especially as my knowledge of C is basic.

Comment: P.S As I said before, the only reason I want it to convert to 8888 is because my C function expects that.

Comment: All I'm saying is that ARGB_8888 takes up twice the amount of memory as RGB_565, and unless you're using images with transparency (an alpha layer), it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: hmm that makes sense! I'm eventually going to be converting the camera stream so I guess there's no alpha. It's a pain as I can't find a simple C or C++ tutorial/class anywhere that performs simple image processing to a RGB_565 bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried to do it in Java? I know it might know seem that great for performance, but i haven't tried it myself, so I can't say.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried it in Java and there's some serious camera lag as soon as a filter is applied. In fact, it's actually quicker when built in Adobe Air...but still too slow. Looks like I'll have to brush up on my low level coding. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: No problem. If it's of any help, I'd perhaps show a preview of any given image effect on a smaller version of the image and then do a background task that creates the high resolution file. Don't know if it works in your case, but it's worth trying, I suppose. The `BitmapFactory.Options` class has an option called `inSampleSize`, which will cause the decoder to subsample the image and return a smaller version.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but so far not satisfactory answered:
Just ran into the same problem the other day.

So far I couldn't solve it and I'm considering writing a converter. Since I'm using OpenCV and they don't support the 565 format.

Saving the image and loading it again with different configuration works, but unfortunately for a real time camera application this is not feasible.

Have a look at this code:

[How does one convert 16-bit RGB565 to 24-bit RGB888?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888?lq=1)