# Android: How to use RGB_565 colors in View.onDraw() to match bitmap colors

Tags: android, view, colors, bitmap, rgb

In my application I have a custom view that renders some bitmaps and draws them to the view's canvas using `onDraw()`. The canvas is filled with a color at first. Essentially I have the following code:

```
public static int COLOR = Color.rgb(200, 50, 50);

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(COLOR);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawColor(COLOR);

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
}
```

I'm expecting the code to create a continuously red screen; the bitmap is rendered in a different shade of red though, so its position is visible. To analyze the colors I made a screenshot of it - the bitmap is drawn with `(206,48,49)` instead of `(200,50,50)`.

Obviously this must have to do with the bitmap using RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888 (which I don't want to use though). So my question is, how can I fill the view's canvas with a RGB_565 color in order to work around those color issues?

I tried converting `(200,50,50)` to RGB_565 by dropping the least significant bits (`red >> 3`, `green >> 2`, `blue >> 3`), but of course that doesn't make a difference here. What does Android do internally to get `(206,48,49)` from `(200,50,50)`? Where is my error in reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out myself...

In my `onDraw()` method, there are two implicit color space conversions:

1. Draw `(200,50,50)` (RGB_888) on RGB_565 bitmap.
2. Draw RGB_565 bitmap on RGB_888 canvas.

`(200,50,50)` is equal to `(25,12,6)` in RGB_565 (`red >> 3, green >> 2, blue >> 3`). Besides, 
not surprisingly, `(206,48,49)` is also `(25,12,6)` in RGB_565.

Now when you convert `(25,12,6)` back to RGB_888, e.g. using [this algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069480/1350193), you get `(206,49,49)` - close enough. I really can't explain why Android returns 48 instead of 49 for the green channel, though. Maybe it's a rounding error or floating point imprecision. A look at the Android source might help, but since this is not an earth-shattering problem, I'll give it a pass.