# How to convert UIImage to and from bitmap int array (rgb565)

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing, bitmap, uiimage

I need to pass my UIImage to an image-processing algorithm that takes int array of the bitmap in `rgb565` format.

Later, it returns image-processed int array which I need to convert back to UIImage.

See it's syntax:

```
int* ImageProcessingAlgorithm(int bitmapArray[], int width, int height);
```

I searched many places but none seem to have UIImage-to-int-array and vice versa conversion. Nearest I found was [this](http://paulsolt.com/2010/09/ios-converting-uiimage-to-rgba8-bitmaps-and-back/) but this deals with char array - I tried fitting it for my purpose but I keep getting various access errors and leaks in UIKit library functions. Maybe I am not managing memory properly or some mistake in int-to-unsigned char-to-int conversion.

I can deal with that part, but still I am not sure it fits my image processing algorithm format (`rgb565`).

I am newbie to image processing and the image-processing algorithm is a black-box for me so I just need the array of ints that I can pass to and from this algorithm.

One thing that I am sure of is that this algorithm returns the same number of array elements that it takes as input - i.e. both input and output arrays represent the same number of image pixels.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I figured, `CGBitmapContextGetData` function returns a void pointer to the array, and it can be converted to any sort of array pointer. What matters is later processing of it.

Here is [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000947-CH1g-CGBitmapContextGetData).

Conversion to rgb565 can be done using this technique, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9069480/1506363):

```
R5 = ( R8 * 249 + 1014 ) >> 11;
G6 = ( G8 * 253 +  505 ) >> 10;
B5 = ( B8 * 249 + 1014 ) >> 11;
```