# To convert RGB16 values to RGB8

Tags: javascript, math, colors

I need to convert RGB-16 color values to RGB-8. The question is twofold.

**First,** what is a recommended way of doing this?

In RGB-8, the topmost value is 255, and in RGB-16 it is 65535, so it seems I can simply divide RGB-16 values to `257`, and this will be enough?

But then why is the following solution for MatLab exists?

> To convert an RGB image from double to uint8, first multiply by 255.
>
> ```
> RGB8 = uint8(round(RGB64*255));
> ```
>
> http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/creating_plots/chimag12.html

And the **second** part of the question, how to do it with JavaScript? I have tried

```
const RGB16 = ...
const RGB8 = new Uint8Array(Math.round(RGB16*255));
```

but it seems it simply returns an array of zeroes.

Comment: `new Uint8Array` argument is the length of the new Uint8Array - personally, I'd do `RGB8 = RGB16 >> 8` i.e. ignore the lower 8 bits of the RGB16

Comment: as far as matlab code ... a double is floating point, probably stores values 0.0 to 1.0 ... so multiplying by 255 and rounding will give integer values 0 ... 255 as required - so, not sure why you think `RGB16*255` is equivalent

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442576/how-does-one-convert-16-bit-rgb565-to-24-bit-rgb888

Comment: discrete math dictates: `8bit_value = ((16bit_value*255)+32768)/65535` so no need for floats beware semiresult is `8+16+1=25` bits wide ... also see: [What is the most accurate way to map 6-bit VGA palette to 8-bit?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/27400/6868)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Converting RGB-16 color values to RGB-8 involves scaling down the values appropriately to fit within the range of 0-255. Your intuition is correct; you can divide RGB-16 values by 257 (not 255) to get the equivalent RGB-8 values.

The reason for dividing by 257 instead of 255 is that 65535 (maximum value of RGB-16) divided by 255 results in 257. This division will ensure that the full range of RGB-16 values (0-65535) is mapped to the full range of RGB-8 values (0-255).

Regarding the MATLAB solution you found, there's a slight difference. In MATLAB, the RGB image is first scaled to the range [0, 1] (since MATLAB's double representation uses values between 0 and 1) by multiplying by 255. Then, it is converted to an unsigned 8-bit integer (`uint8`) using the `round` function to round the values to the nearest integers. This step ensures that fractional values are not truncated, which could happen if a simple cast was performed.

For example, if you directly converted RGB-16 values to RGB-8 using a simple cast, like this:

```
RGB8 = uint8(RGB16/257); % Incorrect
```

Some information could be lost because casting would truncate the fractional parts.

Now, let's address the JavaScript part of the question. The approach you used in JavaScript is not entirely correct. To convert RGB-16 values to RGB-8 in JavaScript, you need to scale the values and ensure they fit within the valid range (0-255).

Here's a corrected way to do it:

```
// Assuming RGB16 is an array of RGB-16 values (e.g., [r, g, b])
const RGB16 = [65535, 32768, 49152]; // Example RGB-16 values

// Convert RGB-16 to RGB-8
const RGB8 = RGB16.map(value => Math.round(value / 257));

console.log(RGB8); // Output: [ 255, 128, 192 ]
```

Comment: the only issue with this is the result is the "map" of input values to output values is not consistent ... the first 129 RGB16's map to RGB-8 value 0, the last 129 RGB16's map to RBG-8 value 255, and between RGB-16 129 to 65407, each block of 257 values map to a RGB-8 (if that makes sense) ... whereas `const RGB8 = RGB16.map(value => value >> 8);` splits the RGB-16 values consistently - i.e. each 256 RGB-16 values map to 1 x RGB-8 value

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, seems to be a clever improvement! ( I'm not @zoldxk `:)` )

Comment: @JaromandaX It seems there are even more pitfalls... https://rgbcolorpicker.com/565

Comment: @yrslv2022 - indeed, but RGB565 isn't RGB-16 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX But the article says _"RGB565 (also known as 16-bit RGB)..."_, right? Or maybe 16-bit RGB is not the same as RGB-16? (Actually, what I try is to create a "calculator" to convert colors used on pre-Mac OS operating system, which was called simply System, and which used some "mysterious" kind of RGB where colors were from 0 to 65535.

Comment: so .. what is RGB8 in that scheme of reality?

Comment: @JaromandaX I suspect my guessings won't be correct and will only introduce more confusion. If you have time to post an answer that will highlight these nuances we are talking about, this would be really great. :)

Comment: I don't have an answer :p and you've already accepted this one, so, surely this answer must be correct